# SELECT Inside a Case in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create an SELECT Statement within Conditional CASE, like this

```
SELECT la.*,
(
  CASE
   WHEN la.SoftDelete = 1
        SELECT SUM(la.LoansAmount) FROM loans_account
   ELSE
        SELECT 0
  END         
) AS outstanding
FROM loans_account
```

I have tried this, but it does not work, I would like to know how to go about something like this please.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?  It is unclear what you ware trying to do, because you have put aggregation functions into a query that has no `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  SELECT la.*, CASE
              WHEN la.SoftDelete = 1 THEN SUM(la.LoansAmount) 
              ELSE 0  END AS outstanding
  FROM loans_account
```

Comment: wow, the two answers works the way I want the code to, now am in a fix as to which answer to choose, thanks guys, you are all awesome

Comment: @Ramos1116 . . . You have discretion over which answer to accept, but you can only accept one.  Typically, the OP would take into account timing (which was first) and explanation (which explains the problem better) when making the choice.  When you have enough points, you can upvote as many answers as you like, but you can only accept one.

Comment: @Ramos1116 it depends on you and surely the the answer from echo_Me is the earliest one so he is the winner

Comment: I really appreciate all these quick answers, this is definitely a place to be

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need the sum of loan amount where softdelete is 1

```
SELECT la.*,
SUM(
  CASE
   WHEN la.SoftDelete = 1
     THEN la.LoansAmount
   ELSE
        0
  END         
) AS outstanding
FROM loans_account la
WHERE ...
```

or if you need the sum from whole where softdelete is 1 then you can do so

```
SELECT la.*, 
  SUM(la.LoansAmount) outstanding 
FROM loans_account la 
WHERE la.SoftDelete = 1
```

Note sum is aggregate function and without group by it will result as a single row assuming the whole table as one group